# Jquery Function on new tags

Tags: jquery

I have created a new input with type file in javaScript function then I have function on new input but it isn't work . I run add() function with click on button

```
<button type="button" onclick="add()" class="btnReadMore btnLoginPage">BUTTON</button>


function add() {

$('#insert').append("<input class='class1' type='file' name='ImagesInText' value='' /><br />");

}

$("document").ready(function () {

$('.class1').on('change', function () {
    alert('changed!');
});
});
```

if I write this input with HTML code ,it acted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `add()` method by adding `add()` in you code, so that file input element could be added to your HTML page and later on when select a file, it will display the alert messge.

```js
function add() {
$('#insert').append("<input class='class1' type='file' name='ImagesInText' value='' /><br />");
}

$("document").ready(function () {
  $('.class1').on('change', function () {
      alert('changed!');
  });
}); 

add();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="insert"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also check here http://jsfiddle.net/NbGBj/

```
<input type="file" id="upload">

$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#upload").change(function() {
        alert('changed!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this working example.

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
  $('body').on('change', '.class1', function() {
    alert('changed!');
  });
});

function add(){
  $('#insert').append("<input class='class1' type='file' name='ImagesInText' value='' /><br />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="insert">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add New" />
```